# Inter thread Communication-Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to java thread. I am unable to give the lock back to the thread from the main thread in the following code. I am getting the undesired output because i am unable to unlock the thread. I want thread to increment the value using thread (goes to wait state after that) and after printing the value, release the lock to print the next incremented value.

```
   class Foo implements Runnable 
    {
         public volatile int value=0,i=0;
        Thread t=new Thread();
       public void method(Thread t) 
        {
          this.t = t;
       }

         @Override
         public synchronized void run() 
         {

            while(i<3)
            {
            value++;//receive and process ACK
             i++;
            try
            {
           System.out.println("im thread here");
            wait();  
            System.out.println("passed wait");
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){
            }
            System.out.println("im notified");
             }//while 
             //}//sync
         }//run method

         public int getValue()
         {

             try
        {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
         catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e);
        } 
             return value;
         }
     }//class foo

     public class ThreadTest
    {
      public static int value1,times=0;
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
        Foo foo=new Foo();
        Thread t=new Thread(foo);
        foo.method(t);
        t.start();
        while(times<3)
        {   
             synchronized(t)
           {
           value1=foo.getValue();
           times++;
           System.out.println(value1);
           System.out.println(t.getState()); 
               try
            {
            t.notify();
             System.out.println("Notify is reached");
             }
            catch(IllegalMonitorStateException ex)
            {
            System.out.println("Thread is blocked");
            } 
        }//sync
        }//while
       }//main
    }//mclasss
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using such low level methods when you have semaphores, etc at your disposal?

Comment: can you elaborate? i do not get you.

Comment: Can you please tell me whats wrong with above code?. I use threads because i run parallel processes.

Comment: This is quite in contradiction with what you said in the question. If you want to run tasks in parallel, your safer bet here is to use an `ExecutorService`; see `Executors` and `Runnable`. But the example you are providing basically issues several threads which compete for one and only one resource, effectively making your program execute sequentially anyway. So, what is it that you really want to do, ultimately?

Comment: But by the time i run the while loop in main method after waiting for some time, i want the value to be incremented to introduce the constant delay for acknowledgement (Which will be in place of value). I want to know  what i should do in the main thread so that the lock on the thread of Foo class can be released. I know something is wrong there in the synchronized block but could not find out.

Comment: So, do you mean to say you want a thread to run when another gives it the permission to do so?

Comment: yes. the permission is from the main thread after processing the value returned from the thread class. But while processing the value,the thread should receive the data from the remote server.

Comment: This is more and more confusing. What is your scenario? Please describe a use case precisely.

Comment: @fge I just need to know how to give the lock back to the thread ( after getting in to wait state ) from the main thread.

Comment: That still does not make much sense. Please see my answer for a usage of Java classes in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this? If you really must use wait/notify & want to use Runnable.

I added a wait block, otherwise the main thread may finish before the background thread increments the value.

```
class Foo implements Runnable {
    public volatile int value = 0, i = 0;
    private Thread backgroundThread;

    public void setThread(Thread thread) {
        this.backgroundThread = thread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (backgroundThread) {
            while (i < 2) {
                value++;
                i++;
                backgroundThread.notify();
                try {
                    System.out.println("background thread wait start");
                    backgroundThread.wait();
                    System.out.println("background thread notified");
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int getValue() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return value;
    }
}

public class ThreadTest {
    public static int value1, times = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        final Thread thread = new Thread(foo);
        foo.setThread(thread);
        thread.start();

        while (times < 3) {
            synchronized (thread) {
                value1 = foo.getValue();
                times++;
                System.out.println(value1);
                System.out.println(thread.getState());
                thread.notify();
                try {
                    thread.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can extend thread:

```
class BackgroundThread extends Thread {
    public volatile int value = 0, i = 0;

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        while (i < 2) {
            value++;
            i++;
            notify();
            try {
                System.out.println("background thread wait start");
                wait();
                System.out.println("background thread notified");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public int getValue() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return value;
    }
}

public class ThreadTest {
    public static int value1, times = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BackgroundThread backgroundThread = new BackgroundThread();
        backgroundThread.start();

        while (times < 3) {
            synchronized (backgroundThread) {
                value1 = backgroundThread.getValue();
                times++;
                System.out.println(value1);
                System.out.println(backgroundThread.getState());
                backgroundThread.notify();
                try {
                    backgroundThread.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really doubt yet it is working properly. After the main thread notifies the backgroundthread, the main thread should finish its whole execution (looping while three times) before letting backgroundthread to execute. I have tried almost the same as you mentioned above but with two different threads (not including main thread) but it does not work in this case. One of the threads finishes its current process even after notification (as mentioned in javadoc) and then let the next thread execute.

Comment: If this is the case, how does it go well with main thread? is it even possible to immediately put to wait after once it notifies other thread and waiting for notification from that thread using sync block?.

Comment: Hi @Struse, not sure what you mean. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you write down what your desired output (and thread flow) is?

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear what you really want to do but we will assume here that you want to run a thread in the background which should run only when its spawner (let's say the main thread) allows it to.

The JDK has several tools for this already, no need to rely on the low level wait() and notify{,All}() methods.

One example of such a primitive is a `CountDownLatch`. It is a one-use entity which allows you to specify the times a given set of threads should `countDown()` it before any threads `.await()`ing for them can trigger.

In combination with the multithread handling classes which appeared as far back as Java 1.5, this means you could do something like this:

```
// Implementation of a Runnable waiting for the counter to trigger
public final class MyWaitingClass
    implements Runnable
{
    private final CountDownLatch latch;

    public MyWaitingClass(final CountDownLatch latch)
    {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            latch.await();
            // do whatever is necessary
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Argh; interrupted before the latch was released
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}

// In the main class:
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadPool();
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1); 
final Runnable runnable = new MyWaitingClass(latch);
executor.submit(runnable);
// do whatever is needed; then:
latch.countDown();
```